# Why server-side shows a null pointer exception (in client server application)?

Tags: java, file-io, client-server, outputstream, fileoutputstream

In my client server application, client sends some commands and the server gives the results back. Now the problem is when the client tries to download a file from the server, by using GET filename command. The program works fine, even it can doesnload the file correctly, but the problem is in the server side's command prompt there is always a null pointer exception error remains. And it happens immediately after I enter the GET command. Error:

[image]

Second issue appears when I remove `fis.close();` line in serverside. It shows another trace error in the server side: Error:

[image]

This is the complete project I am working on:

ClientSide:

```
    package clientside;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientSide {

    private static Socket socket;
    private static PrintWriter outputToServer;
    private static BufferedReader inputFromServer;
    private static InputStream is;
    private static FileOutputStream fos;
    private static final int PORT = 8000;
    private static final String SERVER = "85.197.159.45";
    boolean Connected;
    DataInputStream serverInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String server = "localhost";
        int port = PORT;

        if (args.length >= 1) {
            server = args[0];
        }
        if (args.length >= 2) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }

        new ClientSide(server, port);
    }

    public ClientSide(String server, int port) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(server, port);
            serverInput = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            outputToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            inputFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Client is connected! ");
            Connected = true;
            String line = null;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Type command: ");

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String request = sc.nextLine();

                if (request.startsWith("exit")) {
                    outputToServer.println(request);
                    System.out.println("Application exited!");
                    //outputToServer.flush();
                    break;
                } else if (request.startsWith("pwd")) {
                    outputToServer.println(request);
                    outputToServer.flush();
                } else if (request.startsWith("list")) {
                    outputToServer.println(request);
                    outputToServer.flush();
                } else if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                    System.out.print("\r\n");
                    outputToServer.println(request);
                    outputToServer.flush();
                }
                while (Connected) {
                    line = inputFromServer.readLine();
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if (line.isEmpty()) {
                        Connected = false;
                        if (inputFromServer.ready()) {
                            System.out.println(inputFromServer.readLine());
                        }
                    }
                    if (line.startsWith("Status 400")) {
                        while (!(line = inputFromServer.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                        File file = new File(request.substring(4));
                        is = socket.getInputStream();
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                        serverInput = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        //int bytesReceived = 0;
                        byte[] inputByte = new byte[4000];

                        int length;
                        while ((length = serverInput.read(inputByte, 0, inputByte.length)) > 0) {
                            fos.write(inputByte, 0, length);

                        }

                        /*
                         while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer)) >=0) {
                         //while ((bytesReceived = is.read(buffer))>=buffer) {
                         fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                         }
                         */
                        request = "";
                        fos.close();
                        is.close();
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("\nType command: ");
                Connected = true;
            }
            outputToServer.close();
            inputFromServer.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

ServerSide:

```
        package serverside;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class ServerSide {

        private BufferedReader inputFromClient;
        private PrintWriter outputToClient;
        private FileInputStream fis;
        private OutputStream os;
        private static final int PORT = 8000;
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;
        private Socket socket;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int port = PORT;
            if (args.length == 1) {
                port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            }
            new ServerSide(port);
        }

        private boolean fileExists(File[] files, String filename) {
            boolean exists = false;
            for (File file : files) {
                if (filename.equals(file.getName())) {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            return exists;
        }

        public ServerSide(int port) {
            // create a server socket
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in server socket creation.");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            while (true) {
                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
os = socket.getOutputStream();

                    outputToClient = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    inputFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                    while (true) {

                        String request = inputFromClient.readLine();

                        if (!request.startsWith("exit") && !request.startsWith("pwd") && !request.startsWith("list") && !request.startsWith("GET")) {
                            outputToClient.println("Wrong request\r\n"
                                    + "\r\n");
                        } else if (request.startsWith("exit")) {
                            break;
                        } else if (request.startsWith("pwd")) {
                            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                            outputToClient.print("Status OK\r\n"
                                    + "Lines 1\r\n"
                                    + "\r\n"
                                    + "Working dir: " + file.getName() + "\r\n");
                        } else if (request.startsWith("list")) {
                            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                            File[] files = file.listFiles();
                            outputToClient.print("Status OK\r\n"
                                    + "Files " + files.length + "\r\n"
                                    + "\r\n"
                                    + Arrays.toString(files).substring(1, Arrays.toString(files).length() - 1) + "\r\n");
                        } else if (request.startsWith("GET")) {
                            String filename = request.substring(4);
                            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                            File[] files = file.listFiles();

                            if (fileExists(files, filename)) {
                                file = new File(filename);
                                int fileSize = (int) file.length();

                                outputToClient.printf("Status OK\r\nSize %d Bytes\r\n\r\nFile %s Download was successfully\r\n",
                                        fileSize, filename);
                                outputToClient.flush();

                                try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {

                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[(1 << 7) - 1];
                                    int bytesRead = 0;

                                    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                    }

                                }
                                os.close();
                                fis.close();//NPE is happening here.
                            } else {
                                outputToClient.print("Status 400\r\n"
                                        + "File " + filename + " not found\r\n"
                                        + "\r\n");
                                outputToClient.flush();
                            }
                        }
                        outputToClient.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }

finally{
os.close();
}
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Even if I remove the `fis.close();` line from the server side, it shows `java.net.SocketException: socket closed` error.

Comment: Can you please indicate in the code exactly where the NPE is occurring?

Comment: Oli, thank you for taking time to help me out. The NPE is happening in the ServerSide, at this line   fis.close();  Moreover I will indicate that in my coding. NB removing this " fis.close();" line doesnt solve the problme. rather shows this error in Server side command prompt:   java.net.SocketException: socket closed

Comment: Jonathan Silva has the correct answer to your question. You are using what is called a 'try-with-resources' block here: `try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))`. When that block ends, with the `}`, `fis` will be implicitly closed, so you have no need to close it again. Also, `fis` will cease to exist outside of that try block so attempting to use the variable is what is causing your NPE. Removing the line will remove the NPE. You should also remove the member variable of the same name from your class as it has no purpose.

Comment: but removing that  fis.close() line causes another problem, that I already mentioned.

Comment: This is because there is more than a single problem with your code. Can you add the subsequent stack-trace to the question please?

Comment: what is subsequent stack-trace?, I promise I will soon

Comment: A stack-trace is the location of the thrown exception. You posted a screenshot of the NPE at the top of your question. The NPE is caused by a problem. Removing the `fis.close()` line removes that problem and exposes another one. Post the exception that you get when that line is removed.

Comment: Oli, I have added it please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem is that you are using a try-with-resources block with an assigned variable with the same name as one of your class member variables. Removing the following line will remove the NPE:

```
fis.close();
```

The `SocketException` is being caused by the line:

```
os.close();
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream()) of `Socket::getOutputStream`:

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

Therefore, moving the line `os = socket.getOutputStream();` to just below the line `socket = serverSocket.accept();` line, and also moving `os.close()` to a `finally` block after your final `catch` block should solve this issue.

Comment: thank you for your valuable answer. But referring your "Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket"- I have done exactly what U have said. But then it cant download the file. Please see my code update. I will be happy is you reply my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The socket represented by `fis` is null.

To correct, use this:

```
if (fis != null) fis.close;
```

Comment: Dave, actually that doesnt make any change, the error: java.net.SocketException: socket closed is still remaining

Answer (score 0):

`try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file))`
In this line you are creating a new FileInputStream and using it, and it is not your FileInputStream field, declared before. This `fis` exists only on the "try" block. When you try to close your fis `os.close();` you are trying to close your `fis` field, not the `fis` declared in the `try`.

Use this, instead:

`try (fis = new FileInputStream(file))`. With this you are instantiating a new FileInputStream in your field, not in a new variable.